# All available Cronet providers are disabled. A provider should be enabled before it can be used

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, cronet

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: All available Cronet providers are disabled. A provider should be enabled before it can be used.
       at org.chromium.net.CronetEngine$Builder.getEnabledCronetProviders(CronetEngine.java:365)
       at org.chromium.net.CronetEngine$Builder.createBuilderDelegate(CronetEngine.java:327)
       at org.chromium.net.CronetEngine$Builder.<init>(CronetEngine.java:75)
       at com.vidyakul.exodownload.DownloadUtil.getHttpDataSourceFactory(DownloadUtil.kt:50)
       at com.vidyakul.exodownload.DownloadUtil.ensureDownloadManagerInitialized(DownloadUtil.kt:126)
       at com.vidyakul.exodownload.DownloadUtil.getDownloadManager(DownloadUtil.kt:82)
       at com.vidyakul.exodownload.MyDownloadService.getDownloadManager(MyDownloadService.kt:35)
       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadService.onCreate(DownloadService.java:599)
```

```
 @Synchronized
    fun getHttpDataSourceFactory(context: Context): HttpDataSource.Factory {
            if (!DownloadUtil::httpDataSourceFactory.isInitialized) {
                httpDataSourceFactory = CronetDataSource.Factory(
                    CronetEngine.Builder(context).build(),
                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
                )
            }
        return httpDataSourceFactory
    }
```

```
I am getting this crash on android apps mostly on api 24<=.  
On internet this is only solution avilable.
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-datasource-cronet:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.1.1'
```

I tried this method but still getting
How can you get a location in android when all location providers are disabled?
LocationManager has a method, getlastknownlocation. From the documentation this method: "Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider. This can be done without starting the provider" However this method only returns a ...